# A string of numbers in random order is given and you have to print them in decimal format in strictly decreasing order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking at this challenge:

> Given is a string. This string has its characters shuffled from its original version. The original version is a sequence of digit names, such as "seven nine four eight", but without the spaces. Given the string of letters in random order, print them in decimal format in strictly decreasing order.
>
> #### Example
>
> **Input:** `nieignhtesevfouenr`
>
> **Expected output:** `9874`

I have not found a way to solve this challenge, as a letter may belong to multiple digits. For example the "e" could belong to "eight" or "one" or "seven", or "nine"... How can this be done?

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. You need to make an attempt.

Comment: I have a working solution in python using `itertools.combinations` and a dictionary hardcoding the associations `"zero": 0`, `"one": 1`, etc.

Comment: Interestingly, this problem appears to be very similar to balancing the equation of a chemical reaction.

Comment: You already got some answers but next time please specify the language you are using, also it is really recommended to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question belongs on [codegolf.se], not SO.

Comment: @KenWhite That's a great idea! You can post the challenge!

Answer (score 6):

You can apply this algorithm:

- First count the occurrence of each letter in the input string. For example, the example input string has these occurrences:

  ```
  {
    "e": 4,
    "f": 1,
    "g": 1,
    "h": 1,
    "i": 2,
    "n": 3,
    "o": 1,
    "r": 1,
    "s": 1,
    "t": 1,
    "u": 1,
    "v": 1,
    "w": 0,
    "x": 0,
    "z": 0
  }
  ```

  I also included unused letters, as they would play a role in "two", "six" and "zero", but they are not represented in this example input.

Now we can observe that:

- Every "z" in the input belongs to a "zero";
- Every "w" belongs to a "two";
- Every "u" belongs to a "four";
- Every "x" belongs to a "six";
- Every "g" belongs to an "eight"

If you find the number of "z" in the input string, you can deduct there are that many occurrences of "zero", and you can deduct that count from "z", "e",  "r", and "o". That many "0" should be recorded for the output.

Once we have done that for the above, we can continue with the following:

- Every *remaining* "o" belongs to a "one" (since all "zero", "two", "four" were already accounted for by this time).
- Every *remaining* "h" belongs to a "three"
- Every remaining "f" belongs to a "five"
- Every remaining "s" belongs to a "seven"

And after those have been accounted for, we can finally conclude that:

- Every remaining "i" belongs to a "nine"

We can simplify a bit, because some letters don't really play a role in deciding which digits are represented. For instance, in the above logic, we don't care about the number of "n" or "e", so we might as well not reduce their count when we detect a "one", ...etc. The only 10 letters we care about are listed above.

Finally we use the counts for each digit to build the sorted string.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript. It runs the algorithm for the example input. There is no input validation... It is assumed to be a valid combination of digit names:

```js
// reference data. The identifying letter is put at the front, 
//    and the letters that still matter for another digit
//    follow it.
let map = [
    ["zo", "0"],
    ["wo", "2"],
    ["ufo", "4"],
    ["xis", "6"],
    ["gih", "8"],
    ["o", "1"],
    ["h", "3"],
    ["fi", "5"],
    ["s", "7"],
    ["i", "9"]
];

// The algorithm
function decimals(s) {
    // Count occurrences of letters
    let charCount = {};
    for (let c of "efghinorstuvwxz") charCount[c] = 0;
    for (let c of s) charCount[c]++;
    // Recognise digits by their identifying letter
    let digitCount = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    for (let [name, digit] of map) {
        let frequency = charCount[name[0]];
        for (let letter of name) charCount[letter] -= frequency;
        digitCount[digit] = frequency;
    }
    // Build the result string
    let result = "";
    for (let digit of "9876543210") result += digit.repeat(digitCount[digit]);
    return result;
}

// Example run
let result = decimals("nieignhtesevfouenr");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

@trincot fired the first shot with a clever algorithm in javascript.

Here is an adaptation in python, with mostly the same logic:

```py
import collections

def unscramble(s):
  c = collections.Counter(s)
  return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    [[9]*(c['i'] - c['x'] - c['g'] - (c['f']-c['u'])),
     [8]*c['g'],
     [7]*(c['s']-c['x']),
     [6]*c['x'],
     [5]*(c['f']-c['u']),
     [4]*c['u'],
     [3]*(c['h'] - c['g']),
     [2]*c['w'],
     [1]*(c['o'] - c['z'] - c['w'] - c['u']),
     [0]*c['z']]))
```

For comparison, here is a bruteforce method in python, which tries every combination of numbers (with some checks to avoid iterating through combinations which obviously wouldn't have the correct length). The bruteforce solution is about 100 times slower on the input string `'nieignhtesevfouenr'`.

```py
import itertools

def unscramble_bruteforce(s):
  s = ''.join(sorted(s))
  for r in range(len(unscramble.d)):
    if unscramble.min_lengths[r] <= len(s) <= unscramble.max_lengths[r]:
      for c in itertools.combinations(unscramble.d, r):
        if sum(len(n) for n in c) == len(s):
          if ''.join(sorted(''.join(c))) == s:
            return sorted([unscramble.d[n] for n in c], reverse=True)
  return None

unscramble.d = { ''.join(sorted(n)): i for i,n in enumerate(['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve']) }
unscramble.max_lengths = [max(sum(len(n) for n in c) for c in itertools.combinations(unscramble.d, r)) for r in range(len(unscramble.d))]
unscramble.min_lengths = [min(sum(len(n) for n in c) for c in itertools.combinations(unscramble.d, r)) for r in range(len(unscramble.d))]

print(unscramble('nieignhtesevfouenr'))
# [9, 8, 7, 4]
```

To compare a combination such as `['eight', 'seven', 'four', 'nine']` with the scrambled input string `'nieignhtesevfouenr'`, we sort both strings alphabetically: `''.join(sorted(s))` is compared with `''.join(sorted(''.join(c)))`. Alternatively, we could have compared two multisets / `collections.Counter` objects, counting the occurrences of every distinct character in both string and checking that they correspond. Asymptotically, this should be more efficient, but in practice on the input string `'nieignhtesevfouenr'`, it turned out to be about 40% slower.

Comment: very nice use of `Counter`.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my approach based on the count of the frequency of characters & greedily check unique letters like "z" for "zero" & also consider that 2 "n" are required for "nine", etc.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Problem : Derive Telephone Number
void solve(string s)
{
    unordered_map<char,int> mp;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z') s[i]+=32;
        mp[s[i]]++;
    }
    
    int ans[11]={};

    ans[6] += min(mp['s'],min(mp['i'],mp['x']));
    mp['s']-=ans[6];mp['i']-=ans[6];mp['x']-=ans[6];

    ans[8] += min(mp['e'],min(mp['i'],min(mp['g'],min(mp['h'],mp['t']))));
    mp['e']-=ans[8];mp['i']-=ans[8];mp['g']-=ans[8];mp['h']-=ans[8];mp['t']-=ans[8];

    ans[2] += min(mp['t'],min(mp['w'],mp['o']));
    mp['t']-=ans[2];mp['w']-=ans[2];mp['o']-=ans[2];

    ans[4] += min(mp['f'],min(mp['o'],min(mp['u'],mp['r'])));
    mp['f']-=ans[4];mp['o']-=ans[4];mp['u']-=ans[4];mp['r']-=ans[4];

    ans[0]+=min(mp['z'],min(mp['e'],min(mp['r'],mp['o'])));
    mp['z']-=ans[0];mp['e']-=ans[0];mp['r']-=ans[0];mp['o']-=ans[0];

    ans[3] += min(mp['t'],min(mp['h'],min(mp['r'],mp['e']/2)));
    mp['t']-=ans[3];mp['h']-=ans[3];mp['r']-=ans[3];mp['e']-=2*ans[3];

    ans[7] += min(mp['s'],min(mp['e']/2,min(mp['v'],mp['n'])));
    mp['s']-=ans[7];mp['e']-=2*ans[7];mp['v']-=ans[7];mp['n']-=ans[7];

    ans[5] += min(mp['f'],min(mp['i'],min(mp['v'],mp['e'])));
    mp['f']-=ans[5];mp['i']-=ans[5];mp['v']-=ans[5];mp['e']-=ans[5];

    ans[1] += min(mp['o'],min(mp['n'],mp['e']));
    mp['o']-=ans[1];mp['n']-=ans[1];mp['e']-=ans[1];

    ans[9] += min(mp['n']/2,min(mp['i'],mp['e']));
    mp['n']-=2*ans[9];mp['e']-=ans[9];mp['i']-=ans[9];

    for(int i=9;i>=0;i--){
        while(ans[i]--) cout<<i;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
    string s = "OfNTiWenINeOVE";
    solve(s);
    s = "zWRoTeorzeo";
    solve(s);
    s = "FISEVENVETHNINEREONEE";  // 97531
    solve(s);
    s = "ninenineninesevensevensevensevenfivefivethreethreethreethreeoneoneoneoneoneoneoneone"; //999777755333311111111
    solve(s);
}
```