# How to convert a str "oneninetwoninenine" into 19299

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys I was working on a problem and can't seem to get the correct output.
The question is: Given a string of characters that spell out to numbers, return the smallest number that you can create using all the characters as a string, for example the input is "onenine" the output should be "19", another example is, input is "oneoneninetwo" the output should be "1192" since you can create the strings "one" "two" "nine" "nine" from the input string.

Heres my code so far, it doesn't work for some cases: let's say the input is "oneninetwoninenine" the output is "129" instead of  the expected output which should be "12999"

```
def canConstruct(string, array, memo = dict()):
    if string in memo:
        return memo[string]
    if string == "":
        return 1
    count = None
    for st in array:
        if string.startswith(st):
            size = len(st)
            if canConstruct(string[size::],array) == 1:
                if count == None:
                    count = 1
                else:
                    count += 1
                memo[string] = True
                return memo[string]
    memo[string] = False
    return False

def integerConvert(array):
    numbers = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']
    numbersCache = {'zero':0,'one':0,'two':0,'three':0,'four':0,'five':0,'six':0,'seven':0,'eight':0,'nine':0}
    numbersRef = {'zero':0,'one':1,'two':2,'three':3,'four':4,'five':5,'six':6,'seven':7,'eight':8,'nine':9}

    for num in numbers:
        if canConstruct(num,array):
            for char in num:
                array.replace(char,"",1)
            numbersCache[num] += 1
    result = ""
    print(numbersCache)
    for key,value in numbersCache.items():
        result += (str(numbersRef[key]) * value)
    return result
            
print(integerConvert('oneninetwoninenine'))
```

Comment: This doesn't really require dynamic programming, though, does it? [A string of numbers in random order is given and you have to print them in decimal format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962820/a-string-of-numbers-in-random-order-is-given-and-you-have-to-print-them-in-decim/68968372#68968372)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a lot simpler than you might think.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
"""Number Replacement
Jerod Gawne, 2021.09.15 <https://github.com/jerodg>"""

NUMBERS = {'zero': '0', 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4',
           'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8', 'nine': '9'}


def main():
    inpt = 'oneninetwoninenine'

    for k, v in NUMBERS.items():
        if k in inpt:
            inpt = inpt.replace(k, v)

    print(inpt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic decomposition task, or "tokenization" task. That's a topic from formal languages (also compiler construction).

In general, you might want a "(first) longest match" analysis, also called "[Maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)", in case multiple matches are possible, which is the case in programming languages, when you try to decide if `123.456` is an integer or a floating point number (the 3-long prefix is an integer... but there's a longer prefix).

```py
words = {
    'zero': '0', 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4',
    'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8', 'nine': '9'}

def analyze(source):
    analysis = []
    while source: # or: len(source) > 0
        viable_prefixes = [
            prefix for prefix in words
            if source.startswith(prefix)]
        
        if not viable_prefixes:
            raise ValueError("can't tokenize remainder", analysis, source)

        prefix = max(viable_prefixes, key=len) # maximal munch

        analysis.append(words[prefix])

        source = source.removeprefix(prefix) # Python 3.9+
        # source = source[len(prefix):] # before Python 3.9
    
    return analysis

inputs = '''
    oneninetwoninenine
'''.split()

for inpt in inputs:
    print(">>>", inpt)
    output = analyze(inpt)
    print(output)
```

```
>>> oneninetwoninenine
['1', '9', '2', '9', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it !
The issue is that you iterate using a for loop in `integerConverter`, when you should be iterating with a while loop. You should have something that looks like this :

```py
 i :int = 0
 while i < 10:
        num = numbers[i]
        if canConstruct(num,array):
            for char in num:
                array.replace(char,"",1)
            numbersCache[num] += 1
        else : # there are no more occurences, let's search for the next number
            i += 1
```