# Jumbled numerals, find the optimal order to select numerals so that every character is used

Tags: python, string, algorithm, time-complexity

I was recently asked a question in the interview, the problem statement roughly said,

given a jumbled word that contains numerals in random order, find the integer form of the numerals in the sorted order.

numerals = `zero`, `one`, .... `nine`

input: a string: `enenoin`

output: `19`

explanation: In the input string, there is `one` and `nine` in random order, so we return `19`.

another example:

input: a string: `enenoinone`

output: `19`

explanation: we only consider 1 instance per numeral and the integers are presented in sorted order.

After encountering the problem, without much thought, I started to write the following greedy solution:

```py
import sys

numerals = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]

for line in sys.stdin:
    # take the input string
    # idea: we store each numeral strings zero to nine in a list
    # then, we check the input string
    # as, the string is in random order, we only have to find the count of each character
    # for example, if a string contains 2 z, 4 e, 2 r and 5 o, how many zero can we find in that string?
    # answer is min(2, 4, 2, 5) = 2, we can make at most 2 zero, as we have only 2 z and 2 r.
    # now, we know there are 2 zero in the string, so we append 0, 0 to answer and continue

    # step 1: count the frequency of each character
    freq = {} # hashmap/dict

    for char in line:
        freq[char] = freq.get(char, 0) + 1 # we use get(char, 0) because if char is not in freq, return default value 0
    
    # step 2: for each numeral, we try to count, how many instances of that numeral exist in the string

    numeral_count = {} # another dictionary to store the count of each numeral in string

    for numeral in numerals[::-1]: # traversing in reverse order
        count_numeral = 9999999 # we initialize with a large number, as we will apply minimum, min of any value and a large number is that value, so it's a initialization placeholder
        for char in numeral:
            count_numeral = min(count_numeral, freq.get(char, 0)) # we take the min of count of each character of that numeral

        for char in numeral:
            if char in freq.keys():
                freq[char] -= count_numeral # updating the frequency, as we have already used this amount of characters for current numeral     
        numeral_count[numeral] = count_numeral
    
    print(numeral_count)
        

    # step 3: now, we just add the count of each numeral to a list and make that list to a string

    ans_list = []

    for i, numeral in enumerate(numerals):
        if numeral_count[numeral] > 0:
            ans_list.append(i)

    ans_str = "".join(str(a) for a in ans_list)
    print(ans_str)
```

In the mid-way, I realized the greedy solution will definitely fail in cases, where we choose some numeral but later found out there are some unchosen characters meaning the choice was wrong.

One such case:

`fonineur`

we can initially greedily choose one as one of the numerals, but later we will find out, there are many left-out characters.

I was short on time and there was not many hard cases on the test set, so I just experimented with the order of the numerals, and somehow the following order passed the test cases (no doubt the test cases were pretty weak).

`numerals = ["eight", "seven", "six", "three", "zero", "four", "five", "nine", "two", "one"]`

But I am still not sure how to find the algorithmically most efficient (time complexity) algorithm for this problem, probably in O(n), n being the length of the string.

Comment: How many numerals could you have in the input?

Comment: @DaniMesejo in the original problem statement, the numerals were fixed always `zero` to `nine`.

Comment: (z)ero, t(w)o, fo(u)r, si(x), ei(g)ht are simple, they all have a unique letter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962820/a-string-of-numbers-in-random-order-is-given-and-you-have-to-print-them-in-decim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962820/a-string-of-numbers-in-random-order-is-given-and-you-have-to-print-them-in-decim) (not voting because my vote automatically closes the question).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look first at the even numerals: zero, two, four, six, eight. Each of these numerals has a unique letter, one that does not appear in any other numeral (these letters are: z, w, u, x, g, respectively). So if we see one of these letters in the string, we know for sure to which numeral it belongs and we can remove all its letters from the string. We repeat this until we have removed all the even numerals.

Next look at the numerals one, three, five and seven. Now that the even numerals have been removed, these numerals may be uniquely recognized as well, by the letters: o, t, f, v, respectively. Thus we can remove all occurrences of these numerals.

Finally, the remaining string (if any) must consist of one or more instances of nine.

Now let's try to implement this idea with a single pass over the input string:

Go through the string and count the number of occurrences of the letters z, w, u, x, g, o, t, f, v.

The number of  occurrences of z, w, u, x, g are just the number of occurrences of the numerals zero, two, four, six, eight, respectively.

As for the occurrences of o, t, f, v, we have to apply simple calculations. For example, the letter o, which we would like to represent the numeral one, appears also in zero, two and, four, so the number of occurrences of one is o-z-w-u. Likewise we can calculate the number of occurrences of three, five and seven.

Finally, we can calculate the number of characters left in the string, and if there are any, we know that the numeral nine appears in it as well.